Is the frequency dependence of Joule heating due to the skin effect?
In this question, I'm considering two separate effects:

Joule heating, in which energy in a good conductor is lost as heat due to the dissipation of energy during charge carrier collisions.
The skin effect, whereby the current distribution is pushed outward toward the "skin" of a conductor at high frequencies.

Andrew Zangwill's 2013 Modern Electrodynamics textbook (Sec. 17.6.3) claims that there is a frequency dependent increase in resistance due to Joule heating,
$$
R_S = \sqrt{\frac{\mu \omega}{2\sigma}},
$$
where $R_s$ is the surface resistance of the conductor, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $\mu$ is the permeability of the conductor, and $\sigma$ is the conductivity. He seems to derive this equation from skin depth considerations.
Is the frequency dependence of Joule heating simply due to the skin effect, or are both these effects frequency dependent in their own right?

That heating is indeed such because of the frequency dependence of the skin depth, hence, of the skin effect. If you check the equation above it you can see the rational behind this surface resistance $R_S$, it contains $\delta$ that is frequency dependent explicitly. In the formula  the "Joule" heating is represented by $\sigma$ that in principle can be but in practice up to RF and in normal intensities is frequency independent.

OK, let me see if I'm following what you're saying @hyportnex . (1)The skin depth effect does seem to be contributing at least some (if not necessarily all) of the dissipative heating in this scenario. This makes sense because in order to arrive at that formula for $R_S$ you need to consider the skin depth. However, (2)when we think of Joule heating, we're usually considering an effect that actually changes the conductivity/resistivity of a material, and THAT effect isn't particularly frequency-dependent. Did I get that right? Thanks!

yes, that is what I meant except for "...Joule heating ... actually changes the conductivity/resistivity of a material", which happens if $\sigma$ is temperature dependent. That could be the case for very large and slow current fluctuations but I do not think that this was in your question.
